# How can I get the physical location of my root directory of website?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, root

How can I get the location of the physical root directory of my website in VB.Net?

I am using visual studio 2008 and vb.net

Answer (score 6):

Call `Server.MapPath("~/")`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

but as **SLaks** said:

```
Server.MapPath("~/")
```

will work fine.